# ArcGIS Pro SDK set rotation / angle field in renderer

Tags: symbology, rotate, arcgis-pro-sdk

I'm in the process of converting an Addin written in ArcObjects to an ArcGIS Pro Addin. I need to rotation everything in a point layer using the values stored in the ANGlE field. In ArcObjects I was able to define a rotation renderer like this then apply to the entire point layer,

```
pRotationRenderer.RotationField = "ANGLE"    ' ANGLE is the name of a field in the feature class
pRotationRenderer.RotationType = esriSymbolRotationType.esriRotateSymbolGeographic
```

How do I achieve this using the ArcGIS Pro SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I've not yet had a chance to develop in ArcGIS Pro but a quick whizz around their API help file I would suggest you explore the [CIM](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/sdk/api-reference/#topic44.html) model and have a look at the [symbology examples](https://github.com/esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProSnippets-Symbology) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I've already combed through most of the examples but couldn't find a way to pass the angle column in. Each point's angle are different and there are hundreds of points in a layer I really don't want to have to loop through each point and set the angle one by one.

Comment: @Yannie could [this](https://community.esri.com/message/596064) help?